# Saving the result of a SQLite query as a Python variable

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.x

The problem I'm dealing with is, I want to save a sqlite3 query result in a variable, I created the following code:

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
c=conn.cursor()
#this is implicit, but there is no xxx row in my table, condition and something 
#arent real parameters for my query
qry=("SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE condition=something")
y=c.execute(qry)
print(y)
```

when I run this code I get the following in the print:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01FCD6A0>
```

now, if for example I used a for cycle to print row in that query:

```
for row in c.execute(qry):
    print(row)
```

I would have no problem, but I want to save the value that the query prints in a variable, it should be noted that I am trying to save a query that has a single row and single column, ex: `('EXAMPLE',)`

Is there a way I can save a single row, single column query in a variable and then print it? Should I install some module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `fetchone` with index 0 `[0]`:

```
c.execute(qry)
y=c.fetchone()[0]
print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I was thinking, is there a way to save a multiple row query in a list? 
ex: list=[('somehting','xxx'),('another','yyy')]
I figured i need to use a for cycle and I managed to make the following:
    row=[]
    for x,y in c.execute("SELECT nombre, clave FROM empleado"):
        print(x,y)
        z=(x,y)
        row.append(z)

Comment: sure, if it's a one query with many rows, just loop and append to the one list. If my answer solved your problem mark it as accepted. thanks